# A javascript variable defined outside a function is 'undefined' within the function

Tags: javascript

Why is `MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS`  `undefined` in the following snippet?

If `var MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS  = 40;` is put inside the function, then `MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS` is `40`, but if outside the function,
then `MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS`  is always `undefined`.

```
var MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS = 40;


function wait_until_MM_restarts()
{
    restart_timeout_start_seconds = get_cookie( "restart_timeout_start_seconds" )
    elapsed_restart_seconds =  elapsed_seconds( restart_timeout_start_seconds )
    append_debug_message( elapsed_restart_seconds + "/" +   MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS )
    if( elapsed_restart_seconds > MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS )
```

Comment: It shouldn't be. I can think of things that might cause that effect … but would have to see the rest of the function to tell. It is usually a good idea to provide snippets of code that **can be run** to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I think you have to provide some more context. Better, create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: I tend to avoid globals.  I understand your interest in why this is happening, it's a good question (+1).  However, I would pass MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS into the wait_until_MM_restarts() function as a parameter.

Comment: Chances are pretty good that `MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS` is defined in some other scope (inside some other function) and isn't available from this function because as you've shown it here, it would work just fine.

Comment: It seems to work with this attempt at a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qUhQV/ I second @jfriend00's suggestion that there's a possibility it's a scope problem.

Comment: For instance, I get `undefined` here in the `console.log(MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS)`: http://jsfiddle.net/qUhQV/1/ (@jfriend00 - Was that about what you were thinking?)

Comment: @JaredFarrish - your problem is that you redefined the variable as an undefined local variable inside your function when you added this line to the function: `var MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS;`.  Remove that and it works.  A local variable of the same name overrides a global variable.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I realize that; I was trying to replicate the result the OP was describing, which is it's `undefined` although at a glance it "looks" like it should work.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I thought you were to OP when I read your comment.  I was thinking that the OP has `MM_SYSTEM_RESTART_SECONDS` defined in some other scope that is not the global scope, like in a document ready function or something like that.

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell: Don't leave hanging questions like this. People tried to help you and you ignored them

Answer (score 2):

This just bit me. If you call the function before/above the variable declaration the variable might be undefined.

For example

```
f("before");

var value = 99;
function f(msg)
{    
  alert("msg=" + msg + " value=" + value);
}

f("after");
```

results in:

```
msg=before value=undefined
msg=after value=99
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUhQV/4/